# How to join two of the same query with a different parameter (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query in MSAccess called `ClaimQry` which prompts the user for a parameter, `valuationDate`.  I want to run `ClaimQry` with some valuation date, say, 1/1/2011 and then run the same query with another valuation date, 1/1/2012 and join the two result sets based on a field, `claimNumber`.

I tried

```
SELECT ClaimQuery.Total, ClaimQuery_1.Total
FROM ClaimQuery 
INNER JOIN ClaimQuery AS ClaimQuery_1 ON ClaimQuery.[Claim #] = ClaimQuery_1.[Claim #];
```

But I was only prompted to enter a single valuation date instead of two (thus my resulting data was incorrect).

Edit: Starting to think my question might not be clear, so I'll try to give an example.

Suppose I run `ClaimQuery` and feed it 1/1/2011 for the `valuationDate` parameter.  I might get a result set like

```
Claim# Total
123    100
231    200
132    300
```

Then I run `ClaimQuery` and feed it 1/1/2012 for the `valuationDate` parameter and I get

```
Claim# Total
123    400
231    500
132    100
213    600
```

Now, I want to perform a join on those two sets, and get something like

```
Claim# Total1 Total2
123    100    400
231    200    500
132    300    100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Access will allow you to build a query which uses a parameter query twice and have the db engine recognize two separate instances of the same parameter name.

I suspect the closest you can get is to add the query as one data source, and add a subquery which uses the first query's SQL but with a different name for its parameter.

So if *ClaimQry* looks like this ...

```sql
PARAMETERS date1 DateTime;
SELECT [Total], [Claim #]
FROM YourTable
WHERE date_field = [date1];
```

This query should work ...

```sql
PARAMETERS date2 DateTime;
SELECT ClaimQuery.Total, ClaimQuery_1.Total
FROM
    ClaimQuery 
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [Total], [Claim #]
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE date_field = [date2]
        ) AS ClaimQuery_1
ON ClaimQuery.[Claim #] = ClaimQuery_1.[Claim #];
```

That is probably only half of what you wanted.  But I don't believe we can get you the rest.

Answer (score 0):

what Ive done is to save 2 instances of the same query and on one of them I set `year(P)-1` so latter i call both instances with a `union all` and they share the same parameter -> just 1 input 2 results

```
select * from
Query_1 
union all 
select * from
Query_1_1
```